# export-csv powershell with custom column type

Tags: excel, powershell, ms-access, powershell-2.0

I'm exporting an AD report via power shell using the code below.

`$Get-ADUser -Filter 'enabled -eq $true' -SearchBase "OU=Staff,OU=Users,OU=OSA,DC=domian,DC=org" -properties mail, employeeID | select employeeID, mail, ObjectGUID | Export-CSV "C:\Reports\ADExports\Students.csv" -notypeinformation`

It outputs the csv file and everything looks fine except, the 'Data type' of all columns are set to 'Short Text'.

I require the Employee ID column type to be 'Numbers'. Is it possible to export a csv with custom field type.

I hope this make sense.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Do you open your csv file with Excel? If yes, I suppose it's an Excel and not a PowerShell issue since your code looks about how i'd do it.

Comment: What does the output look like, are they split with ","?

Comment: CSVs are plain text files by design for portability. Its _mostly_ up to the opening program how it interprets that data.

Comment: Thank you all for replies. Ok, here's my dilemma. Basically, i'm exporting two .csv reports using Powershell and trying to run a live query on access to get an merged out put. However, i'm unable to run a live query to due to a 'type mismatch in expression' error. (because on the export CSV1's common field type is 'short text' and CSV2's common field type is 'number')

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok guys, I'm going to assume that you cannot export a csv via powershell with custom data types.

However, I found a way around my issue. I've converted the data type when importing the csv in to access and managed to solve my issue.

If anyone's interested you can find the exact issue and solution here - [Joining Two Tables with Different Data types MS ACCESS - 'type mismatch in expression' error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626744/joining-two-tables-with-different-data-types-ms-access-type-mismatch-in-expre)

Thank you for bring the 'ImportExcel' module to my attention. Now i know there's module available for this and you can do quite a bit on excel manipulation.

Thank you all for your comments/answers.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

CSVs are plain text and do not contain type information. However, you can use [the following module](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages/ImportExcel/5.3.2), which provides an `Export-Excel` cmdlet. This cmdlet takes various Excel parameters, including a `-NumberFormat`.

```
$x | Export-Excel -Numberformat 'Number' -Path 'test.xlsx' #This worked for me.
```

You will probably have to play around with it a little depending on your exact use case. Good luck!

Comment: I'll have a go at this. Thank you.