# Joining Two Tables with Different Data types MS ACCESS - 'type mismatch in expression' error

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm trying to run a query on access using two live CSVs which has a common field with different data types(numbers and short text). I've discovered that you can join different data types using 'CStr'. I've added the 'CStr' to my code on the sql view. Please find the see the code below.

This gives me the output i want on access and i can now see the output when i click on 'datasheet view'. However, when i try to export the data (i'm actually trying create a export specification so that i can export a csv using macro) as a csv i'm getting a 'type mismatch in expression' error message.

Here's my code:

```
SELECT Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Forename, 
       Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Surname, 
       Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Reg, Students.objectGUID
FROM Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups INNER JOIN
     Students
     ON CStr(Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id) = Students.employeeID
WHERE (((Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Reg)="12E"));`
```

I've also tried adding 'CStr' on both sides. as below, but experiencing the same issue.

```
FROM Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups INNER JOIN
     Students
     ON CStr(Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id) = CStr (Students.employeeID)
WHERE (((Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Reg) = "12E"));`
```

And of course, without 'CStr' i can't even view the output on 'datasheet view'. Every time when i click on datasheet view it's giving me the 'type mismatch in expression' error message.

Any help in resolving this would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance.

Additinal info: the data types are EmpoyeeID is 'Short Text' and Person ID is 'Number'

Comment: It isn't just `CSTR` - if `Students.employeeID` is a long data type then leave that as is and change the join to `CLNG(Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id)`.  Check the [Type Conversion Functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/functions/type-conversion-functions) for a full list.  Keep in mind that this will slow the query down as it needs to convert each value - and as you've found,  you can't view graphically.

Comment: Just FYI, the data types are EmpoyeeID  is 'Short Text' and Person ID is 'Number'

Comment: `ON Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id = CLNG(Students.employeeID)` should work then.

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook - the Reference to Type Conversion Functions (VB) saved me today when needing to convert from Text to Double in an Access Query.  Thank you.  My job is safe for another day.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK guys, I've managed to resolve this issue, It turned out to be simple in the end. This is what i did.

Basically, I re imported the linked table. This time on the import window i clicked on 'advanced' and changed the data type to 'short text' on the 'person ID' column to match with the 'employeeID' data type. And then all problems solved. (I didn't know you could do this)

Thank you all for your replies. Going through your comments guided me to the right path.

Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Try the other way round:

```
ON Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id = Val(Students.employeeID)
```

and/or prevent *Null* errors:

```
ON CStr(Nz(Sixthform_Reg_Year_Groups.Person_id, 0)) = Nz(Students.employeeID)
```

Comment: Thank you for this. Again, both of these are working. And displaying the expected outcome on Access when i click 'datasheet view'.

However, when i try to export a CSV i'm getting the 'type mismatch in expression' error.

To export i go to: External Data --> Text File --> name.csv and click ok and the error pops up. (i'm actually trying create a export specification so that i can export a csv using macro)

Comment: You could try using the working query to import the data to a table, then export this table.

Comment: @Gustav  `Nz()` should be avoided in queries. Use `Iif(...is null..)` instead. See this excellent page: http://allenbrowne.com/QueryPerfIssue.html ( a must read :-)