# Joining on different data types

Tags: ms-access, types, inner-join

I'm attempting to do an inner join on `CardID`, which is present in 2 tables:
 `PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD` and `tExceptionsAll2`.

In `PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD` it is a 'Number' and in `tExceptionsAll2` it is 'Short Text.'
I've looked at answers to similar questions posted on  Stackoverflow and implemented them, but I'm still getting an error.

I am unable to change any formatting in `PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD`; several other queries in different databases rely on `tExceptionsAll2` having the current formatting and data types it has.

Here's what I have:

```
SELECT  tExceptionsAll2.ID
        , tExceptionsAll2.CardholderName
        , PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID
        , tExceptionsAll2.CardType
        , tExceptionsAll2.Duration
        , tExceptionsAll2.ExceptionType
        , tExceptionsAll2.STL AS [Exp STL]
        , tExceptionsAll2.CL AS [Exp CL]
        , PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card STL]
        , PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT AS [Card CL]
        , tExceptionsAll2.TerminationDate
FROM    PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD INNER JOIN tExceptionsAll2 ON (PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.CARD_ID = CAST (tExceptionsAll2.CardID AS INT)) AND 
                                                          (PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.PERSON_ID = tExceptionsAll2.CardholderUIN)
WHERE   (((tExceptionsAll2.STL)>0) AND 
         ((tExceptionsAll2.CL)>0) AND 
         ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.TRANS_LIMIT_AMT)<>[tExceptionsAll2].[STL]) AND 
         ((PCARDS_ILL_DBO_CARD.MONTH_LIMIT_AMT)<>[tExceptionsAll2].[CL]) AND 
         ((tExceptionsAll2.TerminationDate) Is Null));
```

Here's the error:

[image]

Comment: `CAST (tExceptionsAll2.CardID AS INT)` isn't correct Access syntax.  Use `CLNG(tExceptionsAll2.CardID)` to change it to a long data type.

Comment: Also have a look at [Joining two tables with different data types in MS Access](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52626744/joining-two-tables-with-different-data-types-ms-access-type-mismatch-in-expre#comment92187931_52626744)